# android in Camera how to set focusable Area in api 14 or greater

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

i tried to add focusable area in **"Camera.getParameters()"** but don't reflect in Camera surface view.

my code like this

```
Camera.Area area = new Area(new Rect(-500, -500, 500,500), 0);\\put 0 or max 1000 weight but not any changes.
ArrayList<Area> listArea = new ArrayList<Camera.Area>();
listArea.add(area);
parameters.setFocusAreas(areas);
camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

there are any problem in code or if this is wrong style to apply focusable then help me plz.. how perticular area can focus in camera view macro mode.

Comment: You have a '0' as weight in Camera.Area.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have set the focus mode to one of these:

> Focus area only has effect if the current focus mode is FOCUS_MODE_AUTO, FOCUS_MODE_MACRO, FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO, or FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE.

From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getFocusAreas()

Answer (score -1):

did you tried calling getFocusareas() first ?
check first if the getFocusareas() returns a non-zero value and then try to call setfocusareas()

Comment: getFocusAreas() just returns a List of focused areas that would have been set by you. This is not analogous to the getSupportedXxx functions.